# How can I change the original variable in lua

Tags: function, variables, lua, var

I want to change the original variable so the functions prints a different answer. I'm new to Lua, is this possible and how can I do it?

Here's my code:

```
io.write("Hello, what is your first player's name? ")
local name = io.read()
io.write('How old is Player 1? ')
local age = io.read()

function Recall()
    print("Your player's name: " ,name, "\nYour player's age: " ,age, "\n")
end

Recall()

io.write("What is your second player's name? ")
local name = io.read()
io.write('How old is Player 2? ')
local age = io.read()

Recall()
```

When I call the function the second time, it prints the name and age in the first input. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You created new locals and lose the access to locals with the same names.

To fix that remove `local` near second `name` and second `age`. (Near `Player2`).

As alternative solution you can make parameters to `Recall` function and pass arguments in it.

Answer (score 1):

right idea, just tweak it a little so you aren't using the same variables

```
io.write("Hello, what is your first player's name? ")
local name1 = io.read()
io.write('How old is Player 1? ')
local age1 = io.read()

function Recall( name, age )
    print("Your player's name: ", name, "\nYour player's age: ", age, "\n")
end

Recall( name1, age1 )

io.write("What is your second player's name? ")
local name2 = io.read()
io.write('How old is Player 2? ')
local age2 = io.read()

Recall( name2, age2 )
```

Comment: oh thanks, i tried doing something like that but I don't understand how you use stuff inside the brackets.

Comment: those variables act as local scope, specific to that function, which don't exist anywhere outside of it.  you can reuse the variable names if you want, if that's specifically what you are going for, but sometimes that can confuse values, especially in the beginning, so it's best to use unique names for new items when you're trying to learn.